# Related list contacts not displaying in lookup filter in search results

Tags: lookup, search, lookup-filter, global-search

i have created lookup filter in Vehicle object for contact. 
 i want to see related account object contacts in vehicle object driver(contact) lookup field.
 when i am search related contacts driver lookup filed related contacts successfully showing in my sandbox(in my sand box having 50 contacts only).

but same situation in my production lookup filter related contacts not showing(in my production having 15000 contacts). so how to display
 bulk contacts time my account related contacts.

What criteria should I apply?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked permissions for the records? Also may be records do not satisfy filter criteria? This search list shows only limited number of records, you can search for more records by entering name/other field.

Comment: @rahul gawale, Thanks for quick reply, But same filter criteria working in sandbox edition. am getting issue in production edition. compare to sandbox permissions also same in production. records only differ. entire sandbox edition having 50 contacts, in production having total contacts 15000. related records(contact) maximum two only. that one/ two related records not showing in lookup search result

Comment: have you tried to search some records by name?

Comment: yeah searched, related contacts only displaying lookup search result reaming contacts not displaying..

Answer (score 4):

The lookup window shows "recently viewed" records when there is no search text. This is a list pulled from the MRU (Most Recently Used) cache, which only stores about 200 records per object per user (which is why the Lookup window reads "Recently Viewed Contacts").

Even with a lookup filter, you are required to view those records and have them in the MRU before they appear by default; the rest of the time you still need to do a search by name in order to find the records you want, which will be further restricted by the lookup filter. In other words, if you type "Smith" in the search box, it will only return people matching that name from the account selected in the other field.